# C# calculations visual studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, character, calculator, trigonometry

I have two questions on a program I am creating that is a calculator (I know, wow, so amazing). I am trying to give it a Sin button but anytime I try to use it, it will not allow me to use it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

/*This is an app that will be used for carrying out claculations
  entered by the user. I am attemtpting to include keyboard shortcuts
  also.*/
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /* ------------Declaration of needed variables to carry out mathematical functions------------ */
        string input = string.Empty;
        string operand1 = string.Empty;
        string operand2 = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;

        /* ------------MainWindow, not altered------------ */
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /* ------------Number and number customization buttons------------ */
        private void Decimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += ".";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Zero_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "0";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void One_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "1";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "2";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Three_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "3";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Four_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "4";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Five_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "5";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Six_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "6";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Seven_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "7";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Eight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "8";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        private void Nine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "";
            input += "9";
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text += input;
        }

        /* ------------Operation buttons------------*/
        private void Minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '-';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '+';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Divide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '/';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Multiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '*';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Equal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operand2 = input;
            double num1, num2;
            double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
            double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

            if (operation == '+')
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                ViewerDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }

            if (operation == '-')
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                ViewerDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }

            if (operation == '*')
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                ViewerDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }

            if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    ViewerDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewerDisplay.Text = "Undefined";
                }
            }

            if (operation == 'S')
            {
                result = Math.Sin(num1);
                ViewerDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewerDisplay.Text = "0.0";
            input = string.Empty;
            operand1 = string.Empty;
            operand2 = string.Empty;
        }
        private void Fnc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.MainGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.SecondaryGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Sin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            operand1 = input;
            operation = 'S';
            input = string.Empty;
            input = "Sin(";
        }

        private void Cos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Tan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I also would like to know how to design different characters for the button such as a square root emblem.

Comment: Can you be more specific, when you say "it will not allow me to use it"? Are you getting an exception, it the button disabled, the click event is not firing?

Comment: @Rufus L I run the App and press the Sin button, then the number I wish to find the sine of, and it acts as though I did not press the sin button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is after pressing the sin button, it adds "Sin(" to the input, and then `TryParse` fails because the input has letters in it. Also, you are calling `Math.Sin` on num1, which is the number entered before you press the sin button.

Just a note, `Math.Sin` returns the result in radians, if you want it in degress, use:

```
Math.Sin((num2*Math.PI)/180)
```

Where `num2` is the last number entered in the box, after "Sin(". I've tested this, I made a crappy calculator real quick to do so.

Now, about designing your different characters like the square root symbol. First off, the square root symbol (√) can be put into a button, label, etc, by setting it's `Text` property (`Content` for WPF) to "\u221A". Like this:

```
myButton.Content = "\u221A"; //WPF
myButton.Text = "\u221A"; //WinForms
```

For other symbols, try searching online, if you can't find any, make a picture and set the button's background to that image.

Comment: So where do I insert your "Math.Sin((num2Math.PI)/180)" Code?

Comment: @user3806603 Where you currently have it, in the `equals` method where you have `if (operation == 'S')`. It should replace the current code you have in there.